# Tick-tack-toe (Jumping into C++)

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, tic-tac-toe

The exercise is from Alex Allain's book "Jumping into C++".
From Chapter 10 Practical Problem 4:

> 4. Write a small tic-tac-toe program that allows two players to play
>      tic-tac-toe competitively. Your program should check to see if either
>      player has won, or if the board is filled completely (with the game
>      ending in a tie). Bonus: can you make your program detect if the game
>      cannot be won by either side before the entire grid is filled?

Here's my code. My main goal was a functioning tick-tack-toe game with little concern on the user experience (e.g.: the coordinates a player enters start from 0, or (0,0) coordinate is in the upper left corner no lower left as one would intuitively think). As for coding style I wanted the code to be as DRY as possible, with small, atomic, easy to understand functions doing most of the work.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool checkWin(int board[][3], int player) {
    // horizontal
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (board[i][0] == player && board[i][1] == player && board[i][2] == player) return true;
    }

    // vertical
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (board[0][i] == player && board[1][i] == player && board[2][i] == player) return true;
    }

    // diagonal
    if ((board[0][0] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][2] == player) ||
        (board[0][2] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][0] == player)) 
        return true;

    return false;
}

// TODO implement function if the game is a tie before the last move

bool fillPlace(int board[][3], int x, int y, int value) {
    if (x > 2 || x < 0) {
        cout << "Invalid x coordinate. Try again.\n";
        return false;
    } else if (y > 2 || y < 0) {
        cout << "Invalid y coordinate. Try again.\n";
        return false;
    } else if (board[x][y] != 0) {
        cout << "Place is already filled. Try again.\n";
        return false;
    } else {
        board[x][y] = value;
        return true;
    }
}

void initBoard(int board[][3], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            board[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void printBoard(int board[][3], int size) {
    cout << "-----" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << board[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "-----" << endl;
}

bool isBoardFilled(int board[][3]) {
    bool isFilled = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == 0) isFilled = false;
        }
    }
    return isFilled;
}

int main() {

    int board[3][3];
    initBoard(board, 3);
    printBoard(board, 3);

    int playerOnesTurn = true;
    while (true) {
        int x, y;

        if (playerOnesTurn) {            
            cout << "Player 1's turn" << endl;
            do {
                cout << "Enter x coordinate: "; cin >> x;
                cout << "Enter y coordinate: "; cin >> y;
            } while (!fillPlace(board, x, y, 1));
        } else {
            cout << "Player 2's turn" << endl;
            do {
                cout << "Enter x coordinate: "; cin >> x;
                cout << "Enter y coordinate: "; cin >> y;
            } while (!fillPlace(board, x, y, 2));
        }
        playerOnesTurn = !playerOnesTurn;

        if (isBoardFilled(board)) {
            cout << "The game is a tie.\n";
            break;
        }

        printBoard(board, 3);
        if (checkWin(board, 1)) {
            cout << "Player 1 has won\n";
            break;
        } else if (checkWin(board, 2)) {
            cout << "Player 2 has won\n";
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Avoid `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3964927)

This can cause name collisions because it adds every name in the `std` namespace to the global namespace. For a small program like this one it's unlikely that you'll run into any problems (then again, [maybe not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31593548/3964927)) but it's best to get into the habit of using the `std::` prefix on names in the `std` namespace.

Alternatively, you can introduce [using declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) like `using std::cout;` to add specific names to the global namespace.

### Avoid `std::endl` in favor of `\n`

[`std::endl` flushes the stream, which can cause an unnecessary loss in performance.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/3964927) In `printBoard()` you use `std::endl` three times but you can easily replace some of those uses with `\n`.

### Use a class for the Tic Tac Toe board

Instead of using a 3x3 array it's better to create a class to hold the state of the Tic Tac Toe board, with functions to set or get the value of a place on the board, determine whether or not the board is filled, etc. This allows you to hide implementation details which may change later on -- for example, if your compiler supports C++11 or will do so in the future you may want to change your internal representation of the board to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). If you have a class for the Tic Tac Toe board the external interface would not change, only the code that implements the functionality.

Here's what that class might look like:

```
class Board {
    int board[3][3];
public:
    typedef int value_type;

    // More modern alternative to typedef:
    //using value_type = int;

    Board() {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                board[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // Gets the value of a board place
    int place(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const {
        // Might want to check coordinates and throw an exception (e.g. std::out_of_range) if coordinate(s) are invalid
        return board[x][y];
    }

    // Sets the value of a board place
    // It would probably be better to throw an exception (e.g. std::out_of_range) instead of printing to std::cout
    bool place(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, int value) {
        if (x > 2 || x < 0) {
            cout << "Invalid x coordinate. Try again.\n";
            return false;
        } else if (y > 2 || y < 0) {
            cout << "Invalid y coordinate. Try again.\n";
            return false;
        } else if (board[x][y] != 0) {
            cout << "Place is already filled. Try again.\n";
            return false;
        } else {
            board[x][y] = value;
            return true;
        }
    }

    bool is_filled() const {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                // Return immediately once we find a non-filled place
                if (board[i][j] == 0) return false;
            }
        }

        // All places were found to be filled
        return true;
    }
};
```

(Note the use of `std::size_t` for the coordinate type and the `typedef` for the `int` value type, which mimic practices from the standard library.)

You would no longer need `initBoard()` since the `Board` constructor performs the initialization, and some of your other functions would become member functions of the class. In some cases you can improve the performance of these functions -- e.g. you can keep a count of how many places are filled by incrementing the count each time a new place is filled by `Board::place()`, and then `Board::is_filled()` simply has to check if that count equals 9 rather than checking every place in the board (the performance gain is negligible for such a tiny board but the principle is important).

### Overload `operator<<` for printing the board

`printBoard()` only prints to `std::cout`. You can overload `operator<<` in order to insert the board into any `std::ostream`. Using the above `Board` class the code would look like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Board board) {
    os << "-----\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            os << board.place(i, j) << " ";
        }

        os << '\n';
    }

    os << "-----" << std::endl;

    return os;
}
```

(Note the replacement of some of the `std::endl` uses with '\n`.)

To print the board to `std::cout` you'd simply use `std::cout << board;`, and you can use the same function to print the board to a different `std::ostream` such as a `std::fstream` (for writing to a file).

### Make your code DRYer

In some cases you can make your code DRYer. For example, the code in the `if` and `else` sections is very similar here:

```
if (playerOnesTurn) {            
    cout << "Player 1's turn" << endl;
    do {
        cout << "Enter x coordinate: "; cin >> x;
        cout << "Enter y coordinate: "; cin >> y;
    } while (!fillPlace(board, x, y, 1));
 } else {
    cout << "Player 2's turn" << endl;
    do {
        cout << "Enter x coordinate: "; cin >> x;
        cout << "Enter y coordinate: "; cin >> y;
    } while (!fillPlace(board, x, y, 2));
 }
```

You can put that in a function like this:

```
// Capture Board by reference so we modify the original Board, not a copy
void player_move(Board& board, int player) {
    cout << "Player " << player << "'s turn" << endl;

    std::size_t x, y;

    do {
        cout << "Enter x coordinate: "; cin >> x;
        cout << "Enter y coordinate: "; cin >> y;
    } while (!board.place(x, y, player));
}
```

---

Here's a demo program with some of the changes I suggested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

class Board {
    int board[3][3];
public:
    typedef int value_type;

    // More modern alternative to typedef:
    //using value_type = int;

    Board() {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                board[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // Gets the value of a board place
    int place(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const {
        // Might want to check coordinates and throw an exception (e.g. std::out_of_range) if coordinate(s) are invalid
        return board[x][y];
    }

    // Sets the value of a board place
    // It would probably be better to throw an exception (e.g. std::out_of_range) instead of printing to std::cout
    bool place(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, int value) {
        if (x > 2 || x < 0) {
            cout << "Invalid x coordinate. Try again.\n";
            return false;
        } else if (y > 2 || y < 0) {
            cout << "Invalid y coordinate. Try again.\n";
            return false;
        } else if (board[x][y] != 0) {
            cout << "Place is already filled. Try again.\n";
            return false;
        } else {
            board[x][y] = value;
            return true;
        }
    }

    bool is_filled() const {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                // Return immediately once we find a non-filled place
                if (board[i][j] == 0) return false;
            }
        }

        // All places were found to be filled
        return true;
    }
};

bool checkWin(Board& board, int player) {
    // horizontal
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (board.place(i, 0) == player && board.place(i, 1) == player && board.place(i, 2) == player) return true;
    }

    // vertical
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (board.place(0, i) == player && board.place(1, i) == player && board.place(2, i) == player) return true;
    }

    // diagonal
    if ((board.place(0, 0) == player && board.place(1, 1) == player && board.place(2, 2) == player) ||
        (board.place(0, 2) == player && board.place(1, 1) == player && board.place(2, 0) == player))
        return true;

    return false;
}

// TODO implement function if the game is a tie before the last move

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Board board) {
    os << "-----\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            os << board.place(i, j) << " ";
        }

        os << '\n';
    }

    os << "-----" << std::endl;

    return os;
}

// Capture Board by reference so we modify the original Board, not a copy
void player_move(Board& board, int player) {
    cout << "Player " << player << "'s turn" << endl;

    std::size_t x, y;

    do {
        cout << "Enter x coordinate: "; cin >> x;
        cout << "Enter y coordinate: "; cin >> y;
    } while (!board.place(x, y, player));
}

int main() {
    Board board;
    std::cout << board;

    // should be a bool, not an int
    // alternatively, just use an int which is 1 when it's player 1's turn and 2 when player 2's turn
    bool playerOnesTurn = true;

    while (true) {
        player_move(board, playerOnesTurn ? 1 : 2);

        playerOnesTurn = !playerOnesTurn;

        if (board.is_filled()) {
            cout << "The game is a tie.\n";
            break;
        }

        std::cout << board;

        if (checkWin(board, 1)) {
            cout << "Player 1 has won\n";
            break;
        } else if (checkWin(board, 2)) {
            cout << "Player 2 has won\n";
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I left a few other minor tips in the comments and I didn't make all the changes I suggested (e.g. I did not remove `using namespace std`).

Answer (score 3):

Bug: if the winning move is the one that fills the board, the game ends in draw instead of a win. This is because you check for a draw before you check for a win.

You can simplify things a bit: only the current player can win, so there is no need to check if the other player has won.

`main` doesn’t need a `return 0`, it is implied.

Besides the redundancies already pointed out, `checkWin` is also a bit redundant, you can simply check to see if three values in a row are equal, it doesn’t matter what value they have. Thus,

```
board[0,i] == board[1,i] && board[0,i] == board[2,i]
```

suffices.

That said, a lot of the work done here would be simpler if the board was stored in a flat array with `index = i + 3*j`.

In this case, resetting the board is a simple call to `std::fill`, and checking to see if the board is full is a single call to `std::all_of`. Of course, if the board is a class, as suggested in the earlier answer, then you can implement an indexing operation that converts the `(i,j)` pair to a linear index.

Comment: FWIW, I disagree with an implicit `return 0` on `main()`. Syntax should not be special. Explicit return values are useful.